# including wp-load.php in a themes php file gives HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show an alert to the screen when a form is submitted showing the current logged in user's name. I know I need to include the `wp-load.php` file but whenever I do that like this:

```
<?php
    include('../../../wp-load.php');

    global $current_user;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$current_user');</script>";
?>
```

Upon my form submission I get the whole:

> This page isn't working
>   example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

How am I supposed to resolve this?

Comment: It is all about errors. Try enabling [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/5914775) and look in your log files for more information about why it couldn't fulfil your request.

Comment: Theme files should already have WordPress fully loaded - they execute within its framework. Chances are you're double-including the WP framework as a result and causing conflicts. Just echoing out a raw `<script>` tag isn't a great way of doing this. You're much better off using something like the [wp_footer hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) to do it.

Comment: how do you submit your form? ajax or reload? if the first, you should be able to do an alert on submit. If the second, you should land on a page where WP framework is loaded, an can just check for POST var and trigger your alert